# Ruby - how to eval two numbers and an operator?

Tags: ruby, eval

In Ruby if I set variables:

```
1.9.3-p327 :002 > a=20;b=5;c="-"
```

How can I then do "a b c" and have it return 15

I tried this

```
class Dummy < Object
  def self.calc(a,b,operation)
    return eval(a,operation,b)
  end
end

1.9.3-p327 :006 > Dummy.calc(a,b,c)
```

but I get

```
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
    from (irb):6:in `eval'
```

Answer (score 7):

Technically, the way to do what you want is `eval "#{a}#{c}#{b}"` — this interpolates all the variables into a string.

However, I don't see why you'd use `eval` for this. Since `-` is a method of all the Numeric classes, you could just do `a.send(c, b)` if you wanted to do `a - b`.

Comment: In fact, it's a very bad idea to use eval for this at all. And not send if it's on a network (think of someone writing 1, :instance_eval, 'system(\'rm -rf /\')'? +1.

Comment: Yes both worked.  this is simplified snippet so doesn't make much sense in isolation but was trying to get at the principle and your answer showed that.

Comment: Any other reasons to use send over eval - speed, memory, security etc ?

Comment: @Linuxios: Do you have any choice but to use `send` or something closely equivalent? It seems to me that's mainly about sanitizing your data.

Comment: @Chuck: It's more secure to actually parse the string as a mini language.